# Strange on onchange during initial load LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

Strange behaviour Onchange event which got fired on initial load .I need to hide the button on initial load. How to overcome this behaviour. Attaching here part of code. Thanks in advance.

Updated info: I could able to figure about where it is calling. Onchange event is called during onload only for picklist list field. Once I remove onChange event only on picklist. I am having expected behaviour. There is an article about it. help.salesforce.com/… .. However I need to have an Onchange event for picklist. The referred article suggest to validate onload if the value is changed from UI. Do you have idea of how we can achieve this?

```
                <td>

                  <div class="slds-form-element">   
                  <div class="slds-form-element__label" >
                 <label for="horizontal-output-id-01">Status</label>  
                             </div> 
                                <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                                     <lightning-input-field id="fid2"  field- 
         name="Status__c" variant="label-hidden" style="width:50%" onchange={HandleInlineEdit}> 
           &nbsp; 
  </lightning-input-field>
                                       </div>
                                       </div>
                               </td>
      <div if:true ={isEditable} class="slds-align_absolute-center" style="padding:5px;"> 
                           <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" name="ClickSave" 
            type='submit'>Save</button>
                           <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" onclick= 
                   {canceledit}>Cancel</button>  
                        </div>

  @track isEdit=false;


  //Init
  connectedCallback(){
    this.isEdit=false;
    console.log('editt' , this.isEdit);
    this.ExpSecClass  = 'slds-section slds-is-open';
}
    HandleInlineEdit(evt){ 
    console.log('hANDLEedit' , this.isEdit );
  this.isEdit=true; }

    get isEditable() { console.log('edit' , this.isEdit );
  return this.isEdit ;}
```

Comment: Do you want to hide ```ClickSave``` and ```Cancel``` buttons on init?

Comment: Yes. I would like to show that button only when there is any change in input field (OnChange). However Onchange is called during initial load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@athi i think the problem is that the `isEditable` is not reactive. when the component gets load, `isEditable` is not called.

To hide buttons you can use isEdit as field

```
<div if:true={isEdit} class="slds-align_absolute-center" style="padding:5px;">
   <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" name="ClickSave" type='submit'>Save</button>
   <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" name="ClickCancel" onclick={canceledit}>Cancel</button>
</div>
```

```
    @track isEdit = false;

    //Init
    connectedCallback() {
        this.isEdit = false;
        console.log('editt', this.isEdit);
        this.ExpSecClass = 'slds-section slds-is-open';

    }

    HandleInlineEdit(evt) {
        console.log('hANDLEedit', this.isEdit);
        this.isEdit = true;
    }
```

or make `isEditable` a public property

```
<div if:true={isEditable} class="slds-align_absolute-center" style="padding:5px;">
   <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" name="ClickSave" type='submit'>Save</button>
   <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" name="ClickCancel" onclick={canceledit}>Cancel</button>
</div>
```

```
    @track isEdit = false;

    //Init
    connectedCallback() {
        this.isEdit = false;
        console.log('editt', this.isEdit);
        this.ExpSecClass = 'slds-section slds-is-open';

    }

    HandleInlineEdit(evt) {
        console.log('hANDLEedit', this.isEdit);
        this.isEdit = true;
    }

    @api
    get isEditable() {
        console.log('edit', this.isEdit);
        return this.isEdit;
    }

    set isEditable(value) {
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your detail response. Actually I don't want to call isEditable during load. It is actually happening. I am looking way to prevent it.  Do you know why isEditable() called during load.

Comment: You should find the answer at the end of this article [Data Binding in a Template](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.js_props_getter)

Comment: I could able to figure about where it is calling.  Onchange event is called during onload only for picklist list field. Once I remove onChange event only on picklist. I am having expected behaviour.  There is an article about it. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000352380&language=en_US&mode=1&type=1   .. However I need to have an Onchange event for picklist.  The referred article suggest to validate onload if the value is changed from UI. Do you  have idea of how we can achieve this?

Comment: No really, but now you should ask a question on how to solve this issue.

Comment: Thank you. Updated the question.

Comment: I think it would be better if you create a new post about how to have Onchange event for the picklist. And explain what behavior you need  exactly